# Java Swing: Improving cursor response using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I need to speed up the cursor response which is hovering over a bunch of rectangles. As the rectangles increase in number(or complexity), the straight forward **linear** algorithm of iterating over the rectangles starts to deteriorate.

This hyperlink shows a linear search model(remember to add the break keyword!!!)[linear approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027174/java-swing-mouse-cursor-misbehaves-when-held-over-a-rectangle)

To clearly show what I mean,below is code of a JPanel that has two groups of rectangles.The first group is a List of rectangles on the y-axis, the second group is a List of rectangles on the x-axis.

Keep in mind, that my solution is the best I could think of, of using **Two** threads to concurrently iterate; one thread per List,one for x-axis and other for y-axis. The sub-optimal solution that I abandoned(code not displayed) is where there was a loop within a loop.One loop dedicated for the x-axis rectangles and the other for y-axis rectangles.This,I deemed sub-optimal as searching for a y-axis rectangle through the contain() method (assuming the inner loop is dedicated for y-axis rectangles) imposed an undue overhead by looping over all x-axis rectangles first.

To improve the linear model i thought of this threaded approach to simultaneously engage worker threads.

Btw, am a java novice,especially in multi-threading.

**Problem:**
One thread seems to disturb the performance of the other.The algorithm below is implemented by two wrapper classes extending Thread which both have a method of iterating over rectangles.They each both work excellently if the other is commented out,i.e each works well *individually* and *separately* ,but one takes a performance hit when both start at the same time.

If I join() one thread,isn't that reverting to a **linear model** which is poor search algorithm as rectangles grow in complexity?

(complexity means not only horizontal and vertical, but also diagonal e.t.c rectangles)?

```
public class FlyingSaucer extends JPanel {
    Rectangle2D rec;
    Rectangle2D rec1; 
    List<Rectangle2D> recList;
    List<Rectangle2D> recList2;

    Rectangle2D.Double mouseBoxx;  
    int f = 10;
    int g = 0;
    int s = 10;
    int y = 5;
    int z = 500;

    public FlyingSaucer(){

        //FlyingSaucer needs to quickly identify specific points over given areas
        //enclosed in rectangles.They use a 'divide and conquer' approach where 
        //different types of rectangles are first identified and a worker thread
        //assigned to each category

        mouseBoxx = new Rectangle.Double();
        recList = new ArrayList<>();
        recList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            rec = new Rectangle2D.Double(2+f,10+g,5,1000);       
            f +=50;
            recList.add(rec);                
        }
        f = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            rec1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(2+y,10+s,1000,5);       
            s +=35;
            recList2.add(rec1);                
        }
        s = 10;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        FlyingSaucer fs = new FlyingSaucer();
        Laser laser = new Laser(fs);
        fs.addMouseMotionListener(laser);
        fs.addMouseListener(laser);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fs);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        ((Graphics2D)g).setColor(Color.RED);
        int a = 10;
        int b = 10;

        for(int i = 0;i < recList.size();i++){               
           ((Graphics2D)g).draw(recList.get(i));
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < recList2.size();i++){               
           ((Graphics2D)g).draw(recList2.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Laser implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
    Rectangle2D.Double mouseBox;
    Rectangle2D.Double recx;
    Rectangle2D.Double recy;
    FlyingSaucer fs;
    public Laser(FlyingSaucer fs){
        this.fs = fs;
    }

    @Override public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override public void mouseExited  (MouseEvent e) { }
    @Override public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double x = e.getX();
                double y = e.getY();

                mouseBox = fs.mouseBoxx;
                mouseBox = new Rectangle2D.Double(x-5,y-5,10,10);

                Graphics g = fs.getGraphics();
                ((Graphics2D)g).setColor(Color.BLACK);
                ((Graphics2D)g).draw(mouseBox);

                //thread one for horizontal rectangles
                HorizontalBuffer hb = new HorizontalBuffer(fs,e);
                hb.start();

                //thread two for vertical rectangles
                VerticalBuffer vb = new VerticalBuffer(fs,e);
                vb.start();

                fs.repaint();
                g.dispose();
        }});
    }

    class HorizontalBuffer extends Thread{
        FlyingSaucer fs;
        MouseEvent e;
        List<Rectangle2D> recX;

        public HorizontalBuffer(FlyingSaucer fs,MouseEvent e){
            this.fs = fs;
            this.e = e;
        }

        public void run() {
            recX = fs.recList;
            Iterator <Rectangle2D> recs = recX.iterator();  
            int v = 1;
            while(recs.hasNext()){
                recx = (Rectangle2D.Double) recs.next();
                if(recx.contains(e.getPoint())){
                    System.out.println("X rectangle detected.."+v);
                     fs.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                    break;
                }
                else {fs.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());}

                v++;
            }
        }
    }

    class VerticalBuffer extends Thread{
        FlyingSaucer fs;
        MouseEvent e;
        //List<Rectangle2D> recX;
        List<Rectangle2D> recY;

        public VerticalBuffer(FlyingSaucer fs,MouseEvent e){
            this.fs = fs;
            this.e = e;
        }

        public void run(){
            recY = fs.recList2;
            Iterator <Rectangle2D> recs = recY.iterator();  
            int v = 1;
            while(recs.hasNext()){
                recy = (Rectangle2D.Double) recs.next();
                if(recy.contains(e.getPoint())){
                    System.out.println("Y rectangle detected.."+v);
                    fs.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                    break;
                }
                else {fs.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());}

                v++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ensure your indentation is correct before posting a question next time. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, still new in posting questions here, and was struggling how to post code.Now I see the difference of what I posted and how you have edited it.Thanks again.

Comment: The way you set the cursor is strange. What happens if the mouse is over one of the vertical rectangles but not on any of the horizontal rectangles? With your current code depending on which thread does the last `fs.setCursor();` call it will be either a hand cursor or the default cursor...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "speed up the cursor"?  What is the current behavior, what is the desired behavior, and how do they differ?

Comment: @ThomasKläger what happens is that when the cursor is over the vertical rectangles it changes to a hand cursor,but fails to change to a hand cursor when held over horizontal rectangles.

Comment: @WarrenDew speed up  means  i have a different code(posted as a link named linear model)  that works but is awfully slow in the sense its takes time for the cursor to change into a hand cursor. The current behavior of the posted code is that one thread performs better than the other,specifically, the 2nd thread, where if the mouse is held over vertical rectangles it responds, but the 1st thread, response is cursor simply never changes to hand cursor.

Comment: @WarrenDew@ThomasKläger. The basic idea is iterating over rectangles **concurrently** is faster than iterating **sequentially**..If you concur,then the concurrent method above does not work properly because the cursor does not respond by changing into a hand cursor over horizontal rectangles. It could be my whole approach is wrong, or a simple coding mistake.As of now,i don't understand why when I remove any one thread, and leave the other,regardless of either the 1st or 2nd, the cursor response is fast, but as I add any other one thread, that thread seems to falter, cursor refuses to change.

Comment: Well, in one of my projects I have thousands of graphic objects (not only rectangles aligned to the x / y axis but diagonal lines as well as curve segments) and linear iteration over all objects has never caused a performance problem without resorting to threads. The code that you show has a total of 35 rectangles, so to me it seems that your threading makes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @ThomasKläger what you say is true.What is posted here is a SSCCE of a large code.The rectangles are actually drawn by specialized classes and the linear approach is unacceptably slow.Its obvious it can be improved, thread are just an option am exploring,but indeed, they seem to create more problems.If the linear model can be improved,its ok.I will edit the post and add the specific loop within a loop which loops over all the rectangles.Please if u can run the code on ur machine, you will see the unnacceptally long time that will get you thinking of ways to improve.Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, you have single threaded code that works but is slow.  The code with two threads works for the vertical rectangles - is it fast enough? - but not for the other rectangles.  You assume this difference is because of the threading, but we don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

Your FlyingSaucer class is not thread safe, but you are accessing it from two different threads, HorizontalBuffer and VerticalBuffer.  This is likely to cause problems:  for example, when HorizontalBuffer tries to get the FlyingSaucer `reclist`, it might be getting null and throwing an exception.  Other problems could also occur due to unsynchronized access.  This isn't the easiest thing to debug:  for example, you won't know about the exception unless you are watching the console, since an exception in one thread doesn't terminate a multithreaded program.

You could fix this particular access synchronization problem by making FlyingSaucer thread safe, by properly synchronizing access to it.  However, there may also be other problems; getting a multithreaded application working properly is not simple, and might not be the best approach for a Java novice, which you say you are.

As noted by others in the comments, it's likely that the best solution is not multithreading.  I'd suggest posting a new question with your single threaded solution and asking how to speed it up.  You can mention multithreading in that question, but I'd recommend being open to other solutions as well.

Comment: Okay, indeed it may be not thread safe.I will replaced the Lists & Array List with a vector,which is synchronized.I admit my multi threading attempts are way above my pay-grade,but of course we learn by attempting,making mistakes and correcting them. Am posting a new question as you suggest, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: [REVISED QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290834/java-swing-awfully-slow-cursor-response-when-hovering-over-rectangles)

Comment: @ThomasKluger[REVISED QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290834/java-swing-awfully-slow-cursor-response-when-hovering-over-rectangles)Thank peoples