# Java Swing: Awfully slow cursor response when hovering over rectangles

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, java-2d

Below is code where a user is moving the mouse cursor over a bunch of rectangles and the cursor is supposed to change to a hand cursor while over the rectangles and revert to a default normal cursor when not on top of the given rectangles.

**Problem:**
The solution works,but painfully slow.They are many ways "to skin a cat", therefore we can model the question in many variants and solutions could be of all kinds, but what is constant,*is that we have to loop over each rectangle using an iterator and use the contain() method to ascertain if indeed a given point on the JPanel is within a rectangle or not,and change the cursor accordingly.*

As simple as what is needed to be implemented sounds,i.e change cursor while hovering over specific rectangles, the program starts to slow considerably as I add different shapes and more rectangles.

The code below simply shows rectangles aligned to the x-axis and rectangles aligned to the y-axis.I **split them**(still can combine them into one list) into two List of rectangles.I iterate over the two lists with a while loop within another,each with the break keyword at the appropriate place.

I avoid using just one large list to hold both types of rectangle (or different types of shapes) because

1. I need to add different shapes every other time, and its better and more readable to have different shapes categorized in there own list.
2. I am instinctively trying to shorten a long process by using different list for different shapes and **if possible**,iterate over the right list only and not iterate over other shapes that are unnecessary.i.e One large list will grow linearly and iterate over ***all shapes***to get to the right one ***all the time.***Doesn't the one large list seem not a so smart implementation? Hoping my best that efforts to avoid the One-Large-List is not a case of premature optimization!!!This the point I thought to use threads [to loop over different list concurrently or simultaneously but one thread misbehaves.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283798/java-swing-improving-cursor-response-using-threads?noredirect=1#comment79538180_46283798)

So then, I categorize shapes in different List, as the example below has two Lists.but this trick also fails as I have to iterate over each list sequentially.So I have a while loop within another.I have not avoided iterating over unnecessary list,as one loop must be within another(or start after another), then the inner loop (or the one that follows) pays an undue performance overhead since the first loop is totally unnecessary **if we can ascertain before hand that a shape belongs to a certain group before hand.Mark you,to ascertain if a mouse cursor is hovering over a shape belonging to a List of circle,or a List of rectangles,is what we need to know *beforehand* !! so that we iterate over the specific list.** It even gets better,if at this point you can still follow my reasoning, to know **beforehand** which List a shape belongs to has to been done without the contain() method, since contain() is to be used while iterating **inside** the List!!!

To summarize, the code below is simply a linear iteration over two list. To access the second List,you have to pass through the first.Is there a way one can by pass iterating the 1st list first?

If all my explanations and explorations are all wrong and don't make sense.
**Question.**
Then,how do I improve the cursor response of the code below.

**EDIT**

Sorry for posting code that does not compile, i has so moved on from this code snippet and was playing with my new toys called threads,till i ended up tying myself in an knot which i could not disentangle myself from.The truth is i choose threads as I hope to select the rectangles and move them about using setRect() method.I envisioned that moving around shapes of all kinds in predetermined motions i.e affinetransformation may require threads due to painting, repainting , searching and all manner of hard work that my benefit from some multi-threading.Anyways, the code below compiles and the cursor response is actually **good!!!**.Ouch! I have a similar implementation but probably its slowness is being caused by other classes which draw the rectangles, unlike in this SSCCE where they are drawn by a for loop.

Mean while, if anyone has a way to get this good performance through threads, it would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class FlyingSaucerTwo extends JPanel {
     Rectangle2D.Double rec;
     Rectangle2D.Double rec1; 
     List<Rectangle2D.Double> recList;
     List<Rectangle2D.Double> recList2;

     Rectangle2D.Double mouseBoxx;  
     int f = 10;
     int g = 0;
     int s = 10;
     int y = 5;
     int z = 500;

     public FlyingSaucerTwo(){

    //FlyingSaucer needs to quickly identify specific points over given areas
    //enclosed in rectangles.They use a 'divide and conquer' approach where 
    //different types of rectangles are first identified and a worker thread
    //assigned to each category

     mouseBoxx = new Rectangle.Double();
     recList = new ArrayList<>();
     recList2 = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
         rec = new Rectangle2D.Double(2+f,10+g,5,1000);       
         f +=50;
         recList.add(rec);                
     }
     f = 10;

     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
         rec1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(2+y,10+s,1000,5);       
         s +=35;
         recList2.add(rec1);                
     }
     s = 10;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        FlyingSaucerTwo fs = new FlyingSaucerTwo();
        Laser laser = new Laser(fs);
        fs.addMouseMotionListener(laser);
        fs.addMouseListener(laser);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fs);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
   }

   //@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g); 
     ((Graphics2D)g).setColor(Color.RED);
     int a = 10;
     int b = 10;

     for(int i = 0;i < recList.size();i++){               
       ((Graphics2D)g).draw(recList.get(i));
     }

     for(int i = 0;i < recList2.size();i++){               
        ((Graphics2D)g).draw(recList2.get(i));
     }
    }
    }

     class Laser implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
      Rectangle2D.Double mouseBox;
      List<Rectangle2D.Double> recxList;
      Rectangle2D.Double recx;
      List<Rectangle2D.Double> recyList;
      Rectangle2D.Double recy;
      FlyingSaucerTwo fs;

     public Laser(FlyingSaucerTwo fs){
      this.fs = fs;
     }

     @Override 
     public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override 
     public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override 
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override 
     public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override 
     public void mouseExited  (MouseEvent e) { }
     @Override 
     public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e) { }

     @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
               @Override
               public void run() { 
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                recxList = fs.recList;                        
                recyList = fs.recList2; 
                Iterator <Rectangle2D.Double> recX = recxList.iterator();
                //FIRST LOOP over Y axis rectangles
                while(recX.hasNext()){
                     recx = recX.next();
                     if( recx.contains(p)){           
                         fs.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR)); 

                         break;                     
                     }
                     else if(recyList.size()>=0){
                         Iterator <Rectangle2D.Double> recY = recyList.iterator(); 
                             //SECOND LOOP over X axis rectangles
                            while(recY.hasNext()){
                                 recy = recY.next();
                                 if( recy.contains(p)){           
                                     fs.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR));                                        
                                     break;                     
                                 }
                                 else{
                                     fs.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                                 }
                            }
                     }
                     else{
                         fs.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                     }
                }                      
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Without running the code - immediately consider the need to perform a search on EVERY `mouseMoved` event - instead you could use a Swing `Timer` to eject a small delay, like 250-500 milliseconds between movements, so you're basically waiting for a opportunist moment to do the search. Also consider comparing the last known "good" result first, so if the user hasn't moved beyond the last found rectangle, don't do the search again

Comment: You might also consider looking into an algorithm which provides you list of rectangles based on the distance from the last known point, so you're searching in a relatively "close" range to the cursor - but I'd do this only after you have a decent match

Comment: I don't know why your code is so slow. It looks like you only have 35 objects. Swing has no problem handling changing of the cursor when you hover it over various components. And we can't test your code since it doesn't compile. Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Seems to me like your divide an conquer approach is too complex. Try solving the problem with a single array and iterate only over that array.

Comment: Or use a graph based model, which would allow you to more easily dive into an area based on the rectangle

Comment: Why do you do nested loops? Why do you iterate over all x-rectangles for every y-rectangle? I believe that you should iterate over all y-rectangles and then iterate over all x-rectangles? That's what your threading approach (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283798) does - why not do it in the non-threading approach too?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the timer is an excellent idea!I have an idea of searching from a last known good point,but its complex.Its goes along the lines of having the mouse having a rectangular or circular area surrounding it that **pre-processes** the points around it and stores the result in a List.Since the mouse is completely surrounded by the rectangle, wherever it moves, the rectangular area would have already been at that point, and processed some data.So once the cursor arrives,it doesn't do the searching, but pulls already searched results from the rectangular pre-processor.What do u think?

Comment: @camickr indeed the code is also not compiling.i seemed to have messed up as I had moved on from this linear approach to a threaded approach.Threaded approach compiles,just change the mouse moved code block to the given two loops.Let me try the one array, I may be surprised by its efficiency.

Comment: @camickr i have fixed the code, sorry for the mistake. The  cursor response is actually good!!This SSCCE does not show all the complexity of my real app.I feel I need a threaded approach as shapes will increase in number and complexity.Imagine am creating a 3D lego game, wouldn't some threads do some good? Its just my approach of learning some multi-threading and creating fantastic algorithms, but yes...some wise programmer told me, algorithms should be simpler, not more complex, as complexity drags along some ego, which get in the way eventually.Thank  for helping me give myself a peptalk :).

Comment: Threading is  used when you have a long running task to execute in the background. In this case you want the cursor to change immediately which means the logic needs to execute fast and in real time, not in the background. I have never had a problem searching through an ArrayList of hundred of objects even it is a simple linear search.In any case the code you posted doesn't use Threads and the invokeLater(...) is unnecessary since code invoked from a listener already executes on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr thanks a lot for the guidance.I have observed what is causing the GUI freeze in my app seems to stem from somewhere else which somehow compromises the efficiency of a simple linear search.Let me examine it and see if I can reproduce it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your inner code should be like this:

```
Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
Iterator <Rectangle2D> recs = rowBuffY.iterator();
//FIRST LOOP over Y axis rectangles
while(recs.hasNext()){
    selectRec = recs.next();
    if( selectRec.contains(p)){           
        cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR)); 
        dragging = false;
        moveLine = true;
        break;                     
    }
}
Iterator <Rectangle2D> recX = rowBuffX.iterator(); 
//SECOND LOOP over X axis rectangles
while(recX.hasNext()){
     selectRec = recX.next();
     if( selectRec.contains(p)){           
     cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR);
     dragging = false;
     moveLine = true;
     break;                     
}
tpp.setCursor(cursor);
```

This code checks every rectangle exactly once and gives preference to X axis rectangles, whereas your code checks every X axis rectangle N times (for every Y axis rectangle that the mouse doesn't hover over).

Comment: there is no significant difference betwin what I have and what you have.You check every rectangle exactly once, so do I, which is not the **best** approach.A better approach is to avoid doing and exhaustive brute force search,and do a smaller search which will be quicker,surely, as the rectangles increase,performance falls!Its essentially the same, observe keenly and you will notice your code will also check Y-axis rectangle N times, then move to X-axis rectangle.No rectangle  should be preferred to the other !as all have equal probability of being pointed by the user!!

Comment: @Afroid1000 no, you check every X axis rectangle once for every Y axis rectangle. That means that your example code already checks up to 300 (20 times 15) rectangles (if no match is found), whereas my code checks 35 rectangles (20 plus 15) at most.

Comment: I get you! The inner loop completely goes over **all** Y axis rectangles every time the outer loop checks just for **one** X axis rectangle.You are indeed correct.Now that you have a better linear model which checks sequentially, wouldn't it be even better if each loop was searched concurrently, each loop by its own thread? This SSCCE does not properly reproduce the poor performance in my project which is single threaded where the rectangles are drawn by other specialized classes. but many thanks,

Comment: @Afroid1000, `there is no significant difference betwin what I have and what you have.` - exactly. That is why you keep the code simple until you have a proven problem. If you can't post a SSCCE that demonstrates a problem then we can't help because we can't guess exactly what your are doing.

Comment: `wouldn't it be even better if each loop was searched concurrently,` - again threading works best when you have a task that is NOT CPU intensive. For example if you want to read multiple URLs from the internet. While one thread is blocking waiting for the response the other thread is busy reading the data.

Comment: @Afroid1000 I suggest you use this code and see if it solves your problem.  It's one of two possibilities that I see for causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Kläger suggests, you should un-nest the loops.

If there is still an issue, it probably has to do with the fact that you are calling setCursor() too much.  In particular, in the nested loop example, if the cursor is not in a rectangle, you are calling setCursor() to set the default cursor hundreds of times.  Each time you call setCursor(), the cursor is redrawn, which is a time consuming process.

You need to set the cursor at most once per mousemoved event.  One way of doing this would be to set a boolean value about the desired cursor type while going through the loops, then setting the cursor only at the end, after both loops have exited, based on the boolean value.  For further efficiency, you could also check whether the current cursor is already the one you want, and only call setCursor() if you need to change it.

Comment: I can confirm that `setCursor` is slow. Using a small benchmark with `JMH` it is between 3_000 times (if the mouse is not over the panel) and 10_000 times (if the mouse is over the panel) slower than `Rectangle2D.contains(Point)`

Comment: Nested loops were indeed a bad idea, and  a boolean value indeed will be more efficient @ThomasKlager thanks for the guidance.